# Drag and drop not working on canvas

Tags: wpf

I'm a complete newb when it comes to WPF, so please be patient with me...

I have a window setup that has two basic sections to it - one section on the left that contains buttons to be used for dragging, and another section on the right to where the buttons will be dragged and dropped.

The button section on the left is just a stackpanel with a vertical orientation, and the section on the right is a canvas.

I've spent a few hours digging up various posts and tidbits of code that demonstrate how to implement a drag-and-drop of buttons to a canvas, but unfortunately it's not quite working like I would expect. The following is what occurs.

I can left click on a button in the button section and then drag it to the canvas section, but the mouse pointer never turns into that little drop icon (the one that indicates you can drop the item you're currently dragging) when I'm hovering over just empty canvas. **However**, if I have a TextBox (and presumably any other control) on the canvas then I can click and drag a button from the left section of the form to the TextBox and the mouse pointer **does** turn into the little drop icon to indicate that I can drop the button. It's just not working when I hover over any empty part of the canvas and that is where I need to be able to drop the button!

Here is my xaml. If anything else is needed then please just let me know! Thanks in advance for the help!

```
<DockPanel Margin="2">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Border CornerRadius="6" BorderBrush="Gray" Background="LightGray" BorderThickness="2" Padding="8">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Button Name="btnNewNode" Width="100" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="btnNewNode_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" 
                        PreviewMouseMove="btnNewNode_PreviewMouseMove">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="Images/block.png" Height="16" Width="16" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0">Node</TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
                <Separator BorderThickness="1" Margin="4"></Separator>
                <Button Width="100">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="Images/balloon-box-left.png" Height="16" Width="16" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0">Comment</TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
        <Border CornerRadius="6" BorderBrush="Gray" Background="LightGray" BorderThickness="2" Padding="8">
            <StackPanel Name="stpMain" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="675" Width="900">
                <Canvas Name="canvasMain" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="605" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="900"
                        AllowDrop="True" PreviewDragEnter="canvasMain_Dragging" DragEnter="canvasMain_Dragging" PreviewDragOver="canvasMain_Dragging"
                        DragOver="canvasMain_Dragging" Drop="canvasMain_Drop" PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="canvasMain_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp">
                    <TextBox Text="Test TextBox" Margin="0,150,0,0" />
                </Canvas>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>

    </StackPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Try setting `Background` for the `Canvas`.